# Estimation of $\operatorname{var}[P(X > 20\mid p)]$ while $X\mid p\sim \text{Bin}(100, p)$ and $p \sim \text{Beta}(60, 30)$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, bayesian, estimation

> I have $p \sim \text{Beta}(60, 30)$.
>
> And I have to estimate $\operatorname{var}[P(X > 20) | p]$ while $X \sim \text{Binomial}(100, p)$.

I think I can sample $p$, calculate $P(X > 20)$ by sampling for $X$ for each sample of $p$, derive an array of calculations, and take variance of that array(using a software)

But this involves two processes of sampling, so I wonder if there is anyway to tackle this analytically. Is there any one to help me out?

Comment: Here you have the conditional distribution of $X|P = p \sim \text{Binomial}(100, p)$. Then by law of total probability, you can compute the marginal pmf of $X$ by $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \Pr\{X = x|P = p\}f_P(p)dp$ where $f_P$ is the marginal pdf of $P$. After you obtained the pmf, you can sum them to obtain the desired probability as usual for other discrete distributions.

Comment: @BGM how about if $p | Y =y \sim beta(60, 30)$ instead of $p \sim beta(60, 30)$, where Y is previous observations and $ Y \sim Binom(a, b)$?

Comment: For your situation, use law of total probability again to compute the marginal pdf for $P$ first: $\displaystyle f_P(p) = \sum_{y=0}^a f_{P|Y=y}(p|y)\Pr\{Y = y\}$ then proceed. Sorry I missed your variance part - because the marginal probability itself is a constant, not a random variable. Maybe you are asking the variance of the corresponding indicator $Var[1_{X>20}]$ instead? But for indicator it is well-known that it is equal to $\Pr\{X > 20\}(1 - \Pr\{X > 20\})$.

Comment: Actually you are asked for $\operatorname{var}[P(X > 20\mid p)]$, not for $\operatorname{var}[P(X > 20)]=0$. Corrected the title.

Comment: @Did well, I understand $P(X>20)$ is not random, but $var[P(X>20∣p)]$ does not seem to be what I want. It will be a function of $p$. My process(es) yields a distribution, but what does that distribution mean?

Comment: @Did, oh, is my distribution the distribution of a transformation of $p$?

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought this variance is going to be very close to $0$. You seem to have

- $\mathbb E[p] = \frac23$ and $\mathbb P\left(X \gt 20 \mid p=\frac23\right) \approx 1 - 1.2 \times 10^{-21}$,
- $\mathbb P\left(p \le \frac12\right) \approx 0.00067$ and $\mathbb P\left(X \gt 20 \mid p=\frac12\right) \approx 1 - 5.6 \times 10^{-10}$.

So as a random variable $\mathbb P(X \gt 20)$ is usually very close to $1$, making its variance small

Here is an numerical integration approach in R, which also estimates the variance of $\mathbb P(X \le 20)$, which should be the same but may avoid some precision errors in calculation. Essentially it splits the unit interval into a number of equal length subintervals, find the probability $p$ lies in each, finds $P(X \gt 20)$ conditioned on the value in the middle of each subinterval and estimates the variance from these

```
varest <- function(cases, n=100, T=20, alpha=60, beta=30){ 
  p <- ((1:cases) - 1/2) / cases
  probp <- pbeta(p + 1/2/cases, alpha, beta) - pbeta(p - 1/2/cases, alpha, beta) 
  probXgtT <- 1 - pbinom(T, n, p)
  probXleT <- pbinom(T, n, p)
  meanprobXgtT <- sum(probp * probXgtT)
  meanprobXleT <- sum(probp * probXleT)
  varprobXgtT  <- sum(probp * probXgtT^2) - meanprobXgtT^2
  varprobXleT  <- sum(probp * probXleT^2) - meanprobXleT^2
  c(varprobXgtT, varprobXleT)
  }
```

Trying different numbers of subintervals from $2$ to $2^{20}$ (just over a million) would give

```
> for (cases in 2^(1:20)){
+   print(varest(cases))
+   }
[1] 1.477861e-05 1.477861e-05
[1] 1.053391e-11 1.053376e-11
[1] 7.167600e-13 7.167463e-13
[1] 2.009504e-14 2.007053e-14
[1] 5.551115e-15 5.528506e-15
[1] 3.663736e-15 3.565419e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.152373e-15
[1] 3.108624e-15 3.053590e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.029168e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.023079e-15
[1] 3.108624e-15 3.021558e-15
[1] 2.886580e-15 3.021178e-15
[1] 3.108624e-15 3.021083e-15
[1] 3.108624e-15 3.021059e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.021053e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.021052e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.021052e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.021051e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.021051e-15
[1] 2.997602e-15 3.021051e-15
```

which suggests to me that $\operatorname{var}[P(X > 20)] \approx 3 \times 10^{-15}$

Using the same method would suggest that $P(X > 20) \approx 1-2.76 \times 10^{-11}$

Comment: Sorry, seems I have confused with $P(X > 20 | p)$. Maybe numerical estimation of $var [ P(X > 20) ]$ may be very small because $P(X > 20)$ is not random.

Comment: @moreblue:  $P(X > 20 \mid p=p_0)$ is a function of $p_0$ and thus $P(X > 20 \mid p)$ might be thought of as a function of the random variable $p$.  Thus you can say $P(X > 20 \mid p)$ is also a random variable.  That makes  $\operatorname{var}[P(X > 20 \mid p)]$ meaningful (it is a number but not a function of $p$, since you know the distribution of $p$) and perhaps you can write this as  $\operatorname{var}_p[P(X > 20)]$